# stored procedure in oracle sql developer to insert millions of records using insert into select query?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have to insert the records into one table by select data from another table using insert into select statement.
I have no idea on the count of records from select statement, it can be 1000,  or even millions.

This is what i have sql query to insert the record without stored procedure:

```
insert into table1
select col1,col2,col3 from table2 where condition 
full outer join
select col1,col2,col3 from table2@dblink where condition;
```

Or is there any other way around to do this task.. as using the above query around 1.2 million of records inserted in 45 min. which is too long.

Comment: Have stored procedure in place and let the DB Server work for you rather than running query in your tool. And also disable index, disable logging etc.

Comment: Why do you want to use a stored procedure - what do you think that will improve? I imagine the query is just slow - a full outer join over a database link is probably doing more work than you expect; look at the execution plans for the select on its own and when it's part of the insert statement.

Comment: The above query mentioned worked without any stored procedure for now. If there is requirement then i will create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting the record in above manner works for me now.